# Can I use resources to declare a public variable?

Tags: android, android-resources

In android, I want to use a string-array resource to create a `public static final String` in one of my classes. However, it seems I must call `getResources()` on a `Context` and I can't find any context at the class level. Is this possible?

```
public class DBAdapter {

    Resources res = getResources();
    public static final String[] gradeTypes = res.getStringArray(R.array.gradeTypes);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. If you need the `Context`, you can pass it with constructor:

```
public class DBAdapter{
    private Context mContext;

    public DBAdapter(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
}
```

But anyway you won't have a chance to use it at the `gradeTypes` initialization. Why do you need to declare it as `final`? If you want to use this array at inner classes, you can do it without `final` modifier.

Comment: I want to use it as kind of a global unchanging string array. Instead of doing this, I suppose I can try creating the array from the resource wherever I need it, since I should then have context.